# Drop Down List not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am looking to create a drop down list based on previous selection, I have tried creating one here [fiddle]((http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/krn32/1/), but my second drop down is not populating. What am I missing/doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div>System Selector:
    <select class="systemDropDown">
        <option value="">--Select System--</option>
        <option value="Demandware">Demandware</option>
        <option value="Site Replication">Site Replication</option>
        <option value="3rd Party Request">3rd Party Request</option>
        <option value="Log-in (all others)">Log-in (all others)</option>
        <option value="Log-in (Global Collect)">Log-in (Global Collect)</option>
        <option value="Global Collect Issue">Global Collect Issue</option>
        <option value="Store Locator">Store Locator</option>
        <option value="New Product Request">New Product Request</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>Country:
    <select class="countryDropDown">
        <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".systemDropDown").change(function () {
        var system = $(this).val();

        function fillcountryDropDown(systemCountryOption) {
            $.each(systemCountryOption, function (val, text) {
                $('.countryDropDown').append(
                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
            });
        }

        function clearCountryDropDown() {
            $('.countryDropDown option:gt(0)').remove();
        }
        if (system == 'Demandware') {
            clearCountryDropDown();

            var demandwareCountryOption = {

                SPAIN: 'Spain',
                IRELAND: 'Ireland',
                USA: 'Usa'
            };

            fillCountryDropDown(demandwareCountryOption);
        } else if (system == 'Site Replication') {
            clearCountryDropDown();
            var sitereplicationCountryOption = {

                LONDON: 'London',
                LIVERPOOL: 'Liverpool',
                DERBY: 'Derby'
            };
            fillCountryDropDown(sitereplicationCountryOption);
        }
        var countryOptions = {
            val1: 'text1',
            val2: 'text2'
        };

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

You define a function here:

```
function fillcountryDropDown(systemCountryOption)
{
    // implementation
}
```

And call it here:

```
fillCountryDropDown(demandwareCountryOption);
```

Change the definition to `fillCountryDropDown` and the jsFiddle seems to work at that point.  (Also select jQuery to be loaded, which I'm sure you do on the page but forgot on the jsFiddle.)

Comment: Damn. you beat me by 46 secs

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty: In what way is it not working?  When I make that one change on your jsFiddle (and select jQuery on the left menu), and re-run the code, the second drop-down is populated any time the first one changes.

Comment: @David Sorry David it is working, i had the old jsFiddle open that i was making changes on, my bad, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will not like this!

Javascript is case sensitive ...

Your function `fillcountryDropDown` is not called. you need to change the function name to `fillCountryDropDown`